# RethinkDB: count unique rows within grouped data

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to count all unique rows within grouped data, i.e, how many unique rows exist within each group.

Although `groupedData.distinct().count()` works for relatively small amounts of rows, running it on ~200k rows, such as in my case, ends with "over size limit".

I understand why it happens, yet I can't come up with more efficient way of doing it - is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Count is an expensive thing in RethinkDB to my experience. Especially for count operation that require iterating the whole data set. I myself struggle with this for a bit before.

To my understanding, when you pass groupData to `distinct`, it creates an array, because `groupData` will be a sequence, therefore it has 100,000 element limits.

To solve this, I think we have to use a stream, and count the stream instead. We cannot use `group` because it returns a group of stream, or in other words, an array of stream to my understanding again.

So here is how I solve it:

1. Create an index on the field I want to groups
2. Call distnct on that table with the index.
3. Map the stream, passing value into a count function with getAll, using index

---

An example query

```
r.table('t').distinct({index: 'index_name'})
    .map(function(value) {
      return {group: value, total: r.table('t').getAll(value, {index: 'index_name'}).count()}
    })
```

With this, everything is a stream and we can lazily iterator over result set to get the count of each group.

Comment: I get your general direction, and it indeed helps, yet now the problem is distinct()ing the whole table. It takes forever in my case, even when indexed (>2.5 million docs)

Comment: @Kludge what does your data model look like? Kureikain is right that `count`ing is at the moment an expensive operation, but I'm not sure that the index is set up correctly.

Comment: This is a relatively old question, unfortunately I can't remember :/ btw I'm not sure counting is the expensive part, it's distinct() iiuc